# How to resolve "ITaskbarList3 interface is not supported on this OS version" on XE6

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, taskbar

Delphi XE6 raises

> ITaskbarList3 interface is not supported on this OS version

error at runtime on Vista and XP. It is a known issue in [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124644) and resolved in XE7.

The error comes when the TTaskbar VCL component is placed on a TForm and the application is run on OS prior to Windows 7 (such as Vista or XP).

How one can work around this in XE6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This interface was introduced in Windows 7. It is not implemented by earlier versions. The requirements section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692.aspx) makes this clear. This is of course eminently reasonable since the interface encapsulates functionality that does not exist in Vista and earlier.

On a platform lower than Windows 7 you should not attempt to use this interface. My guess, although you do not state it, is that you are using a VCL wrapper around this interface, rather than the interface itself. All the same, the solution is the same. Avoid the component, or at least the code path, that uses the interface in question.

So, if you encounter the problem because you used `TTaskbar`, make sure that you don't use `TTaskbar` when the program runs on a system that does not support `ITaskbarList3`. Likely this means no longer creating the component using the form designer and instead doing so, conditionally, using runtime code.

Comment: I see. So generally I should avoid putting TTaskbar on my form designer and should create it only if Windows 7 or above is detected. That is easy solution but questionable why Embarcadero designed something which is not having a good fallback.

Comment: They just got it wrong. As they often do. They got task dialog wrong too. Original versions were disabled when themes were disabled. They aren't very good at testing and their VCL devs don't know Win32 very well.

Comment: @GadDLord: Microsoft does not support XP anymore, and Embarcadero does not support XP anymore, and Vista is on its way out, so they did not bother testing `TTaskBar` on versions earlier than Win7, that's all. And as you said, this was fixed in XE7, so they were made aware of the issue, just not in the initial release.